# React useEffect can not update function variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Regarding this part of code:

```
const MyComponent = props => {

    let number = 0
    React.useEffect(() => {
        number = number + 1
        console.log('inside useEffect: ', number);
    }, [number])

    console.log('outside useEffect: ', number);

    return <div/>
}
```

I expect the number to be `1` after executing the `useEffect` but here is the log:

```
outside useEffect:  0
inside useEffect:  1
outside useEffect:  0
outside useEffect:  0
```

My question is why `useEffect` can't update `number`? How can I update a simple variable in `useEffect`?

**Note:** This code is just a sample

Comment: use const number = useRef(0) and then number.current = number.current + 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you see `console.log('outside useEffect: ', number)` executed, it means there's been a re-render triggered. Since you put the log inside the render function body.

Now take a closer look, what else is inside the render function body?

```
let number = 0
```

Of course, this line of code will reset `number` back to `0` every time a re-render is triggered. That's the why.

Ok, what solution we have? `useRef()` it is:

```js
const MyComponent = props => {
    const number = useRef(0);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        number.current = number.current + 1
        console.log('inside useEffect: ', number.current);
    }, [number.current])

    console.log('outside useEffect: ', number.current);

    return <div/>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should use react-hook's [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

```js
const MyComponent = props => {

    const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(0)
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setNumber(number+1)
    }, [])
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log(number)
    }, [number])
    
    return <div/>
}
```

Comment: Any other solution? I don't want `number` to be a state.

Comment: since you want to use the `number` variable inside the MyComponent, you should use state.

Comment: why don't you want number to be in state?

Comment: I'm refactoring a class component to a functional component. I have a huge non-state object with a high change frequency so make it state can affect and reduce performance. I want to set the initial value for it in a `useEffect`.

Comment: what is your purpose to use the `number` in the component?

Answer (score 1):

Your number is not in state, and every time your function is re-renderd your number do not **preserve** value, but create new value, which is initial one (0).

You have three possibilities:

1. Put number in const [number, setNumber] = useState();
2. useRef(number)
3. You can also try to put `number` outside of MyComponent function, and then it should preserve value.

In my opinion preferable way to do this is with `useRef`.